# Skew background image without distortion?

Tags: css

I need to skew the shape of a div that contains a background image, without actually distorting the background image.

Right now I'm using transform: skew(-25deg)

Is it possible to do this without the distortion?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to "un-crop" the image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the background image on a child of the skewed element and then apply an opposite skew to the child. Here's an example:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: skew(0.5rad, 0);
  width: 100px;
}
.child {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 0%, blue 100%);
  height: 100%;
  transform: skew(-0.5rad, 0);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    etc.
  </div>
</div>
```