How to make the background Image in a Skew container not Shewed
I'm trying to make my background image not skew while leaving the flex-container box skewed and was wondering if there was any way I could do this.
I tried making the .first selector as a child of the flex-item to unskew it but that didn't work and now I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.


body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: url(./images/woodbg.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  gap: 10px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.first {
  background-image: url(./images/cocktail1.jpg);
}

.second {
  background-image: url(./images/cocktail2.jpg);
}

.third {
  min-width: 400px;
  border: 0;
}

.fourth {
  background-image: url(./images/marg1.jpg);
}

.fifth {
  background-image: url(./images/marg2.jpg);
}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Drink Maker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="first"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item second"></div>
      <div class="flex-item third"></div>
      <div class="flex-item fourth"></div>
      <div class="flex-item fifth"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769959/skew-background-image-without-distortion
